Implementing "Sweep and prune" - General design of data handling
I am working on a 3D/physics engine using C++ and OpenGL.
Currently I'm in the process of implementing the "Sweep and Prune"-method for collisions checks using AABB (axis aligned bounding boxes). I'm roughly following the method outlined  here (part 1 & 2): https://leanrada.com/notes/sweep-and-prune/
The algorithm works by sorting the min & max coordinates of each axis for each AABB box:

vectors (sorted by coordinate) for the X-, Y- and Z-axises
The algorithm also requires to know if each edge is the minimum coordinate or the maximum.
Also the ID of the entity it belongs to.

For this data I'm using this struct called Edge:
struct Edge {
    int id;
    bool isLeft;
    float coord;

    Edge(int id, bool isLeft, float coord)
        : id(id), isLeft(isLeft), coord(coord) {}
    }
};

Example of Entity class with relevant functions for Edge:
class Entity
{
public:
    int id;
    std::vector<Edge> edgesList;

    std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices;
    std::vector<unsigned int> indices;
    glm::vec3 position;

    // create Edges
    void setupEdges(const std::vector<float>& minMax)
    {
        // Create Edge objects and add them to edgesList
        edgesList.emplace_back(id, true,  minMax[0]); // min_X
        edgesList.emplace_back(id, false, minMax[1]); // max_X
        edgesList.emplace_back(id, true,  minMax[2]); // min_Y
        edgesList.emplace_back(id, false, minMax[3]); // max_Y
        edgesList.emplace_back(id, true,  minMax[4]); // min_Z
        edgesList.emplace_back(id, false, minMax[5]); // max_Z
    }

    // update Edges. The new coordinates are calculated separately in another function
    void updateEdges(const std::vector<float>& minMax)
    {
        edgesList[0].coord = minMax[0];   // new min_X
        edgesList[1].coord = minMax[1];   // new max_X
        edgesList[2].coord = minMax[2];   // new min_Y
        edgesList[3].coord = minMax[3];   // new max_Y
        edgesList[4].coord = minMax[4];   // new min_Z
        edgesList[5].coord = minMax[5];   // new max_Z
    }

To save on performance I want to use insertion sort for the axis-vectors (since generally Entities will not switch places every frame).
Also I would like to update the Edge-structs from inside the Entity-objects and have it automatically update the axis-vectors.
Question: How do I put all Edge-structs from all Entities inside a single vector, while still being able to update the values from inside each Entity (which the structs belong to)? Especially after sorting said vector

Do you have a specific question?

Yes, sorry for being vague:
How do I put all Edge-structs from all Entities inside a single vector, while still being able to update the values from inside each Entity (which the structs belong to)?
Especially after sorting said vector

You need a reference of some sort to be able to manipulate an object from two places. As you may have already found, sorting the vector blows the hell out of (keyword: invalidate) those references as does just about anything you can do with a vector other than look at it. This is one of the downsides of the brutal efficiency of a vector. It's not stable in the face of change. But if you can't point at the vector contents safely, you can have a vector of pointers. This complicates everything you do with a vector and can slow it down considerably. Be sure you need to do this.

Thank you yes that is one of the big problems I have run into. How one needs to re-point each time data changes in a vector. Also re-pointing is an issue since the ordering in the vector also changes. Since entities will also be added I think the list needs to be a vector?

Maybe a better way to go about it is by making a vector with copies of the days and saving the index of each object from the previous sorting. That way one could maybe update the data by index somehow? Thoughts?

An easier solution seems to be just to keep a copy of each Entities Edge-structs in a separate vector and update this vector by Edge-structs ID which corresponds to each Entity.
At least this way I don't have to deal with pointers. A bit annoying to do double updates of coordinates (in each entity and also then in the copied data), but I don't have to deal with pointers this way
